# Cropping PHP array based on another array without using a for loop

Tags: php, arrays

Given:

```
$arr_in=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4);
$keep=array('a','c');
```

What is the most concise way to obtain:

```
$arr_out=array('a'=>1,'c'=>3);  //Keep only original elements who's index is in $keep
```

Comment: `$temp = [];foreach($keep as $value) { if(!empty($arr_in[$value])) $temp[$value] = $arr_in[$value]; }`

Comment: @anonymous  So nothing like 'array_intersect()` or `array_slice()`?  I recognize neither of these work, but thought there might be something else.

Comment: why do you want to sort them out? i mean if you make a foreach loop for $keep you can simply use only the $arr_in-entries you need. so there is no need to sort them out.

Comment: @Bernhard  Don't need to sort them, just remove them.  The new array will be used with a prepared statement which only needs some of the values.

Comment: @user1032531 `array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($keep))`

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion

Comment: @Rizier123  Ah, `array_flip()`!

Comment: @GerardvanHelden  Why do you say "opinion"?  Do you not agree with Rizier's solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as a one-liner with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$arr_out = array_intersect_key($arr_in, array_flip($keep));
print_r($arr_out);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
foreach($arr_in as $key => $val){
    if(in_array($keep, $key))
        $temp[$key] = $val;

}
```

You might want to look into array functions like array-pop.

Comment: I was looking for something like Rizier's comment.  After Bernhard deleted his similar answer as your's, I updated the question, but unfortunately you were in process of giving this answer.  Thank you and sorry for the mixup.